# Change TextField selection color in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, select, usability, textfield

How can I change the select ("highlight") color of an TextField in actionscript 3?  I've got an input textfield with white text on a black backdrop and as a result, selections are invisible, which is horrible for usability.  Thanks!

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var c:Color = new Color(MyTextField);

c.setTransform({rb:255});
```

or for a more up to date approach:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/geom/ColorTransform.html#includeExamplesSummary

Comment: What color object are we supposed to be importing to get this to work?  I'm not finding anything.  I'm guessing that's an AS2 approach??  Following the above link to the ColorTransform documentation isn't clear, either...

Comment: I agree with gmale, this isn't an accurate answer.

Comment: I believe this technique has been supported since AS1 :) worked for me anyway ;)

Comment: The question specifies AS3. This is simply not AS3. My compiler literally bursts into flames just typing in this code...

Comment: This used to work up til Flash Professional CC was released in June 2013 and they dropped backwards compatibility with the Color class. Up til then this was a popular method.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to use the Text Layout Framework, specifically a TextFlow using a SelectionManager.  With the TLF, you can directly control the SelectionFormat properties used for your text.

e.g.

```
TextFlow.defaultConfiguration.focusedSelectionFormat = new SelectionFormat(0x00FFFF);
```

There's a bit of a learning curve to pick up the TLF's way of doing things, but the payoff is significantly enhanced text customization.

Comment: Works perfectly! The only problem is that using TLF makes my SWF increase from 250KB to 656KB! That's a huge amount just for being able to change the selection colour...

Comment: it appears to be because I am also exporting a SWC... Something I have to do in order for the metadata to be compiled (using RobotLegs)...

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find a class doing the job

<del>http://labs.hellokeita.com/2008/03/13/textfield-selection-color/</del>

Reference site is down with its class :(

Here you can find something similar, although not so powerful:
http://yourpalmark.com/2007/08/13/changing-selection-color-on-dynamic-textfields/