# Flex text selection: does it have to be white on black?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, text, textarea, mxml

When you select text in a Text or Label or TextArea (or other) control in a Flex application, the selection is shown in white text on a black background. Always.

I have a request to change that — and it seems to be a simple enough thing to want — but I can't find a style (or property) anywhere that permits that. Any ideas out there about how to do this, or reasons why it definitively *can't* be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Change TextField selection color in AS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072401/change-textfield-selection-color-in-as3)

http://ericlin2.tripod.com/select/selectt.html