# AS3 - Is there a way to change TLF highlight color?

Tags: actionscript-3

I've read this Q&A: [Change TextField selection color in AS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072401/change-textfield-selection-color-in-as3)

But I don't understand the part using `TextFlow`, I tried this:

```
import flashx.textLayout.elements.TextFlow;
import flashx.textLayout.edit.SelectionFormat;

TextFlow.defaultConfiguration.focusedSelectionFormat = new SelectionFormat(0xDC4713);
```

But my TLF didn't seemed to have changed it's highlight color, what is the proper way to use this code or is there a way to change the highlight color in all the textfields in your flash?

Comment: You need to provide more details. This `defaultConfiguration` property is for new `TextFlows` that are created *without a configuration*. So it's possible that: a) no one created any TextFlows (no code shown) b) someone specified their own setting, c) you mentioned "textfields", if you're referring to the `TextField` class: it doesn't use TLF and this setting would have no effect. If you add more context to your question, I think we can find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TLF Text you should use something like this.

```
var fSelFmt:ISelectionManager = textFlow.interactionManager;
fSelFmt.focusedSelectionFormat = new SelectionFormat(0x000000, 1.0, BlendMode.INVERT);
fSelFmt.inactiveSelectionFormat = new SelectionFormat(0x00FF00, 1.0, BlendMode.OVERLAY);
fSelFmt.focusedSelectionFormat = new SelectionFormat(0x00FFFF, 1.0, BlendMode.HARDLIGHT);
textFlow.interactionManager = fSelFmt;
```